Odoo 17 - Having a problem with returning the domain for the field when executing the onchange method
I'm having a problem with returning the domain for the field when executing onchange method. For the code below, it works fine on Odoo version 14. But on Odoo version 17, it doesn't work.
class ChooseDeliveryCarrier(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'choose.delivery.carrier'
    
    service_id = fields.Many2one('ahamove.service', string='Service')
    service_request_ids = fields.Many2many('ahamove.service.request', 'estimate_request_rel',
                                           'choose_id', 'request_id', string='Request Type')
    @api.onchange('service_id')
    def _onchange_service_id(self):
       for rec in self:
          if rec.service_id:
             return {'domain': {'service_request_ids': [('service_id', '=', rec.service_id.id)]}}

This relationship between service_id and service_request_ids are One2Many
class AhamoveService(models.Model):
    _name = 'ahamove.service'
    request_ids = fields.One2many('ahamove.service.request', 'service_id', 'Requests')

class AhamoveServiceRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'ahamove.service.request'
    service_id = fields.Many2one('ahamove.service', string='Service')

Can you guys give me a solution to do this? I want the service_request_ids field to display only according to the selected service_id.

returning domain from onchange is not supported anymore since odoo-14

Thank you for your response, @ipin. Can you recommend for me a solution? I see the feature to return dynamic domain for fields as very necessary for the program.

please refer to @Kenly answer

Use a computed field as a domain for the service_request_ids field
Example:
Python:
service_request_ids_domain = fields.Binary(compute="_compute_request_domain")
    
@api.depends('service_id')
def _compute_request_domain(self):
    for rec in self:
        domain = []
        if rec.service_id:
            domain = [('service_id', '=', rec.service_id.id)]
        rec.service_request_ids_domain = domain

XML:
<field name="service_request_ids_domain" invisible="True"/>
<field name="service_request_ids" domain="service_request_ids_domain"/>


should you convert it to json? rec.service_request_ids_domain = json.dumps(domain) since service_request_ids_domain is char field

Thanks for the comment, the field type should be Binary as in the Odoo source code

Thanks for the response @Kenly, it's working with the Binary field
